# wxPython: how to listen to EVT_KEY_DOWN on SearchCtrl?

Tags: python, wxpython, search-box

In my application I want a search box, probably like the one provided by `wx.SearchCtrl`, with the search button and the cancel button included. I also want to know when the user presses <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd>, so that I can browse through the search results. When I make a demo with `wx.TextCtrl` I can bind the event like this

```
self.textbox = wx.TextCtrl(self)
self.textbox.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyDown, self.textbox)
```

But as soon as I change `textbox` to `wx.SearchCtrl` I cannot catch the event anymore. Can I make the binding work with `wx.SearchCtrl` or do I have to implement my `textbox` so that it looks like one?

If that matters, I'm developing on Ubuntu (Gnome) and the application should work well on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: How are you displaying the search results? Are you using the SearchCtrl menu or are you trying to use something else? What version of wxpython are you using?

Comment: Search results are displayed in a separated ListBox. I use the wxpython included in Ubuntu's repositories. Can't check the version now, but I will update soon.

Comment: The exact version is 2.8.10.1

Answer (score 1):

A workaround seems to be using EVT_KEY_UP, i.e

```
self.textbox.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.OnKeyUp, self.textbox)
```

However, this way the key press is not repeatable (you have to release the key in order for the event to be fired). I'm still looking for better ways.

Comment: You should file a bug report for wxPython to document this problem

Answer (score 0):

Use a different event, [as per the docs](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.SearchCtrl-class.html).

```
self.textbox = wx.SearchCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.OnKeyDown, self.textbox)
```

Comment: They are too different. TE_PROCESS_ENTER only catches Enter, EVT_TEXT only catches character input. I want to catch Up and Down :(

Comment: You can get the key the user pressed in the event handler and perform whatever operation when it matches the up key.

Comment: No, the bound method doesn't get called at all when I press Up or Down (or Left or Right, if that matters).

Comment: EVT_TEXT is used when the contents of a TextCtrl change. You should use EVT_CHAR and then you can check the key codes.

Comment: @Velociraptors: still the same thing, works with `TextCtrl`, doesn't work with `SearchCtrl` :(